# Short s.f. Story, can't remember title, satirical riff on Teenagers Who Saved the Earth (all grown up now)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, humor

This is not a particularly famous or widely-published story, but it may have been anthologized once in one of the popular "Year's Best"-type antho's (or "Best of "If", etc.) -- probably where I read it years ago.

It's a tongue-in-cheek, dryly satirical story, probably pretty short, playing on the clichéd "Teenagers Save the World from Alien Invasion" trope. Here it is years later, All-American (former teenagers) Chip* and Molly* [*I'm making up the names, I DON'T remember them] are now married. They helped save the Earth from some diabolical alien invasion years before, but now life is mundane and lacks the fabulous heroic excitement of their thrilling moment in the sun years earlier. The story basically plays on how reality has set in (marital malaise, job tedium, no one wants to hear them (him?) reminisce Yet Again about "the good old days" when "[remember how] "we saved the Earth from the Aliens!"). I don't remember the ending, but it's basically a wry portrait of the clichéd fresh-faced 1950's kids from various stories/movies, only years on. Anyone know this story? Thanks in advance. (Was delighted when people here came through swimmingly on my earlier short-story query. Ta.)

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but the same theme pops up in *The Incredibles*.

Comment: I didn't even knew that was a cliché. I've read dozens and dozens of science fiction stories, and I'm having a hard time thinking of even one where teenagers save the world from alien invasion. What's the obvious example I'm missing?

Comment: @user14111: I'm having trouble pulling up examples in my head, but I'm pretty certain there are at least a round dozen examples of young-adult literature with a similar theme, usually with the adults never realizing there was an invasion in the first place.

Comment: I haven't read that one, but the sensibility sounds a lot like McSweeney's.  The middle aged disillusionment of (mostly fictional) pop culture icons is pretty much their stock-in-trade.  http://www.mcsweeneys.net

Comment: Sounds almost like a sequel to _Star Smashers of the Galaxy Rangers_, although I don't think anyone got married at the end of that.

Comment: @user14111, SeanDuggan: I can't think of any examples of that *exact* theme, either, but (1) teenagers saving the world (while adults are oblivious): *Buffy, the Vampire Slayer*, (2) kids handling first contact with aliens better than adults: *ET the Extra-Terrestrial*. (3) See also *Gremlins*.

Comment: @PeregrineRook, Sean Duggan: It seems, then, that "kids save the world" is *not* a cliche of real science fiction, though (as to be expected) it's common in kiddie-lit. The best example I can think of is Heinlein's *Have Spacesuit, Will Travel* wherein Kip and Peewee are helpful in saving the Earth first from the wormfaces and then from the Galactics. Of course the Vegan mother-thing also has a lot to do with it.

Comment: Hi again-- thanks all for the suggestions so far.. user14111, I maybe overstated it by calling it a "cliché", but I think the story alluded to cheesy B movies more than any writings.. the idea of teenagers intrepidly trying to overcome some danger (not nec. aliens I guess) that either the adults are skeptical of, or, simply, the teens are on their own in some crisis where THEY have to coral their buddies & overcome this strange danger. Yes, I guess it's not a cite-able cliché if I can't come up with even one specific example! -PeregrineRock, the Buffy allusion is apt. Scoobies overcoming evil!

Comment: (And Sean Duggan, that's probably true as well. I didn't read too much kiddie lit that I can remember-- or at least any that had a science-fiction tinge-- but I think you're right. "Juvenile fiction" abounds, I think, with the common theme or trope of resourceful kids/ teens having to follow their noses, their spidey-senses and their knowledge & experiences that are being ignored/ scoffed at by the grups.. I mean grown-ups. WAIT, I just remembered how much I read the Hardy Boys' stuff.. not sf, & not really exactly the clichè I'm ref'ing, but it too has the Heroic, Intrepid Kids theme, kinda.)

Comment: @BeccaPiano Oh, movies. OK then, *The Blob* is a good example.

Comment: @user14111 Yes! Been too long since I saw that, as a teen myself I think. I just remember goo, gorgeous Steve McQueen, and "The End (?)".<r>There are probably scads of mediocre-to-bad B (or Z) movies with teens and/or kids foiling cheesy monsters' diabolical plans, I bet.

Comment: It's not the same book, but Edgar Cantero's "Meddling Kids" has a similar theme, invlving the grown-up selves of a gang of unmask-the-monster-as-the-amusement-park-owner-in-a-costume Scooby Doo detective-type kids.